# Could negative integer factorials be defined in some way?

Tags: factorial, integers

I know that, calling $F$ such an extension, if we wanted to keep having $$ F(z+1)=(z+1)F(z),$$ letting $ z=-1$ would lead to the absurdity $ 1=0$. Also, $ \Gamma(z)$ has poles at $ z \in \mathbb{Z^-}$. But couldn't we just say this recurrence relation is replaced by some other in $F$ if $z $ is a negative integer? Obviously $ F$ would still derive from some property of factorials.

Comment: Have you heard of $\Gamma(x)$?

Comment: What is the point of having some new value defined for a function if that value breaks the usual rules for that function?

Comment: @ccorn For convenience of notation, just as $0!$ is defined as $1$. I've seen negative integer factorials defined as being $0$, although I cannot remember the context.

Comment: @BruceZheng: Typically, it's the reciprocals that are defined as $0$, consistent with $\Gamma$ having a pole there. Such things are consistent with at least a subset of the usual rules, that's where the convenience comes from.

Comment: @ccorn Well, this extension would still derive from one or more particular properties of the original function. Only that recurrence relation (which is somewhat fundamental, I admit) would fail to hold.

Comment: Sure, if you want to replace $F(n)=n\cdot F(n-1)$ by something different for $n\le 0$, for example $F(n)=\frac23 F(n-1)^2$, then it is possible to extende $F$ to $\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\qquad\quad$ I believe you might be interested in [Hadamard's $\Gamma$ function, or Luschny's factorial](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html):

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to ascribe the values using the following formulas:

$$\Gamma(-n)=\lim_{h\to0} \Re (\Gamma(-n+ih))$$

or, alternatively,

$$\Gamma(-n)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\Gamma(-n+h)+\Gamma(-n-h)}2$$

This way we can ascribe values to Gamma function at negative integers: 
$$\Gamma(0)=-\gamma$$
$$\Gamma(-1)=\gamma-1$$
$$\Gamma(-2)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{\gamma }{2}$$
$$\Gamma(-3)=\frac{\gamma }{6}-\frac{11}{36}$$
$$\Gamma(-4)=\frac{25}{288}-\frac{\gamma }{24}$$

etc.

This does not preserve the main functional equation however. Although the values are consistent with some other places where Gamma function is used, for example in determining the integration constants in context of differintegral:

$$(1/t)^{(s)}|_{t=1}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{- i \omega }}{(-i\omega)^s} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(1/t) e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega=\Gamma(s+1)\cos(\pi s) $$

Answer (score 0):

It's called gamma function and expands to rational, real, even complex numbers. (Of course including the negative ones to answer your question correctly)

Comment: I'm referring to negative integers.

Comment: $\Gamma$ has poles at $0,-1,-2,\ldots$

Comment: @ccorn I know, and in fact I'm talking about another extension, if it is possible, since anyway $ \Gamma$ is not the only one.

Comment: You can define anything you want, but if you want it to be analytical, it is unique and $\Gamma$

Comment: @Pieter21 Yes, I remembered something about that, thank you for recalling.

Comment: Analyticity is not enough to pin down $\Gamma$ uniquely; see Lucian's answer.