# Why isn't Euler's gamma function defined for negative integers?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

So today I'll be holding a seminar on Euler's gamma function, as part of my uni work... I'm happy with my presentation but I am unsure what to answer if the question pops up "why isn't the gamma function defined for negative integers?"

Comment: Why isn't $x\mapsto\frac1x$ defined as $0$?

Comment: Related: [Could negative integer factorials be defined in some way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/986364/42969)

Answer (score 6):

One of the defining properties of $\Gamma$ is that
$$
x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)
$$
Assuming $\Gamma(1)$ is strictly positive, what could $\Gamma(0)$ possibly be to respect this relation? We would want $0\Gamma(0)=\Gamma(1)$. That can't happen. So it must remain undefined there.

Now we can go backwards: If $\Gamma(-1)$ were defined, we would simply set $\Gamma(0)=-\Gamma(-1)$. But we know $\Gamma(0)$ can't have a value. So neither can $\Gamma(-1)$. And so on.

This is a bit handwavey, and not a real proof. But it should, at the very least, serve as evidence and justification.